# Flutter ListViewBuilder with 2 different types of elements (eg. profile pic on top and profile details list after that)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm aiming for a page that looks like this -

> ListView
>
> > [Profile _ Image] {Swiper}
> >
> > [SizedBox]
> >
> > [Profile Detail-1 ]{Text}
> >
> > [Profile Detail-2 ]{Text}
> >
> > [Profile Detail-3 ]{Text}
> >
> > [Profile Detail-N ] {Text}

I looked at the Flutter [cookbook example of MultiList](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list)

The cookbook expects all items in the listview to implement the same class. What if this is not possible.

I have tried using `index` of ListViewBuilder to return Widget based on index.

Is that the right approach? Shall I be doing something completely different - like siglechildScrollView?

Thanks!

Edit1-
Current Code that I'm using -

```
return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
        if (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels == scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
          this._feedBloc.loadMore();
        }
        return false;
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 72),
          itemCount: this._postItems.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (this._postItems.length == index) {
              if (this._isLoadingMore) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  height: 36,
                  width: 36,
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            }

            if(index==0){
              return WdgtProfileImage();}
            else if(index==1){
              return SizedBox(2.0);}

            return WdgtUserPost(
              model: this._postItems[index],
              onPostClick: onPostClick,
            );
            //return postItemWidget(
            //    postItem: this._postItems[index], onClick: onPostClick);
          }),
    );
```

Comment: Add your code so I can help where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) instead of the normal `Listview.builder`. The `CustomScrollView` takes in a list of slivers to which you can pass/use a [SliverList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html) to build a list.

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    //A sliver widget that renders a normal box widget
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: WdgtProfileImage(),
    ),
    //A sliver list
    SliverList(
      //With SliverChildBuilderDelegate the items are constructed lazily
      //just like in Listview.builder
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return WdgtUserPost(
            model: _postItems[index],
            onPostClick: onPostClick,
          );
        },
        childCount: _postItems.length,
      ),
    ),
    if (_isLoadingMore)
      //your loading widget shown at the bootom of the list
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          height: 36,
          width: 36,
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
  ],
)
```

Additional links to docs:

- [SliverList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html)
- [SliverChildBuilderDelegate](http://SliverChildBuilderDelegate)
- [SliverToBoxAdapter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverToBoxAdapter-class.html)